# Android Listview Item : How to set custom height of the item?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, styling

I have the following list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/AppTheme.ListViewItemStyle_1">

    <View android:id="@+id/data_view_stripe"
        style="@style/AppTheme.RedStripe"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/data_iv_main"
        style="@style/AppTheme.ImageBig"
        android:src="@drawable/web_icon_weight"
        android:contentDescription="Item icon"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_title"
            style="@style/AppTheme.ListItemDefaultHeading"
            android:text="BP - diastolic"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_value"
            style="@style/AppTheme.WrapContent.Value"
            android:text="87 mmHg"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_occurence_desc"
            style="@style/AppTheme.WrapContent.Calendar"
            android:text="Daily at 8:00"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_overdue"
            style="@style/AppTheme.WrapContent.Schedule"
            android:text="Overdue (Today at 8:00)"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_test_time"
                  style="@style/AppTheme.WrapContent.Schedule"
                  android:text="Overdue (Today at 8:00)"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/data_btn_favourite"
                 style="@style/AppTheme.RatingBasic"
                 android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                 android:paddingRight="0dp"
                 android:contentDescription="Favourite button"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/data_iv_trend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
            android:contentDescription="Progress indicator"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/data_btn_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/background_white"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Info"
            android:contentDescription="Information button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

With the following styles:

```
 <!-- Base ListVIew Item -->
    <style name="AppTheme.ListViewItemBase" >
        <item name="android:background">@color/background_white</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <!--  ListVIew Item style 01-->
    <style name="AppTheme.ListViewItemStyle_1" parent="AppTheme.ListViewItemBase">
        <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:descendantFocusability">blocksDescendants</item>
    </style>
```

I tried to set the custom height of the item to 50dp using the:

```
android:layout_height
```

Height was changed in Android Studio layout preview, but if i deployed app into real device height of the item stayed unchanged.

How can i set custom height for list item using styles please?

Many thanks for any advice.

**EDIT:**
By Your suggestion i tried following example which is not working for me (item height is still same).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    >

    <View android:id="@+id/data_view_stripe"
        style="@style/AppTheme.RedStripe"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/data_iv_main"
        style="@style/AppTheme.ImageBig"
        android:src="@drawable/web_icon_weight"
        android:contentDescription="Item icon"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_title"
            style="@style/AppTheme.ListItemDefaultHeading"
            android:text="BP - diastolic"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_value"
            style="@style/AppTheme.WrapContent.Value"
            android:text="87 mmHg"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_occurence_desc"
            style="@style/AppTheme.WrapContent.Calendar"
            android:text="Daily at 8:00"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_overdue"
            style="@style/AppTheme.WrapContent.Schedule"
            android:text="Overdue (Today at 8:00)"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_tv_test_time"
                  style="@style/AppTheme.WrapContent.Schedule"
                  android:text="Overdue (Today at 8:00)"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/data_btn_favourite"
                 style="@style/AppTheme.RatingBasic"
                 android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                 android:paddingRight="0dp"
                 android:contentDescription="Favourite button"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/data_iv_trend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
            android:contentDescription="Progress indicator"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/data_btn_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/background_white"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Info"
            android:contentDescription="Information button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/AppTheme.ListViewItemStyle_1"
android:layout_height="50dp">

Comment: try here this one. not in ListViewStyle_1

Answer (score 1):

Remove

1. `style="@style/AppTheme.ListViewItemStyle_1"`
2. **Where is**  `android:orientation`

Then.You can try this way ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
```

**Note**:
set `android:orientation=""` as `horizontal` or `vertical` as per your requirement

Comment: @redrom okay .You can set `parent=”@android:style/Widget.ListView”` .From https://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/android-how-to-customize-default-themes-and-styles/

Comment: parent cannot be set in Linear layout, can be set only in <style>